# Does redis-4.0.11's cluster mode need Sentinel?

Tags: redis

I found that Sentinel is mainly used for promoting slave to master automatically when master failed.

I also found that redis-4.0.11's cluster mode seemly also have this function itself.

So when I use redis-4.0.11's in cluster mode, do I need a Sentinel ?

Answer (score 1):

NO, you don't need sentinels in cluster mode.

When a master is down, the cluster will promote one of its slaves to be the new master automatically.

Comment: I think so too. But why there is a Sentinel component? Is it a legacy product?

Comment: @JarShaw Sentinel provides high availability for Redis, NOT Redis Cluster. If Redis runs in non-cluster mode, you can use Redis Sentinel to do auto failover and other stuffs. Check the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) for detail.